# list.find(closure) and executing against that value

Tags: grails, groovy

Really my question is "Can the code sample below be even smaller? Basically the code sample is designed to first look through a list of objects, find the most granular (in this case it is branch) and then query backwards depending on what object it finds.

1 - If it finds a branch, return the findAllBy against the branch

2 - If it finds a department, return the findAllBy against the department

3 - If it finds an organization, return the findAllBy against the organization

The goal is to find the most granular object (which is why order is important), but do I need to have two separate blocks (one to define the objects, the other to check if they exist)? Or can those two executions be made into one command...

```
def resp
def srt = [sort:"name", order:"asc"]

def branch = listObjects.find{it instanceof Branch} 
def department = listObjects.find{it instanceof Department}
def organization = listObjects.find{it instanceof Organization}

resp = !resp && branch ? Employees.findAllByBranch(branch,srt) : resp
resp = !resp && department ? Employees.findAllByDepartment(department,srt) : resp
resp = !resp && organization ? Employees.findAllByOrganization(organization,srt) : resp

return resp
```

What I'm thinking is something along the lines of this:

```
def resp
resp = Employees.findAllByBranch(listObjects.find{it instanceof Branch})
resp = !resp ? Employees.findAllByDepartment(listObjects.find{it instanceof Department}) : resp
resp = !resp ? Employees.findAllByOrganization(listObjects.find{it instanceof Organization}) : resp
```

But I believe that will throw an exception since those objects might be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten it up a bit more with `findResult` instead of a for in loop with a variable you need to def outside:

```
def listObjects // = some predetermined list that you've apparently created
def srt = [sort:"name", order:"asc"]

def result = [Branch, Department, Organization].findResult { clazz -> 
    listObjects?.find { it.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) }?.with { foundObj ->
        Employees."findAllBy${clazz.name}"(foundObj, srt)
    }
}
```

`findResult` is similar to `find`, but it returns the result from the first non-null item rather than the item itself.  It avoids the need for a separate collection variable outside of the loop.

Edit: what I had previously didn't quite match the behavior that I think you were looking for (I don't think the other answers do either, but I could be misunderstanding).  You have to ensure that there's something found in the list before doing the findAllBy or else you could pull back null items which is not what you're looking for.

In real, production code, I'd actually do things a bit differently though.  I'd leverage the JVM type system to only have to spin through the `listObjects` once and short circuit when it found the first Branch/Department/Organization like this:

```
def listObjects
def sort = [sort:"name", order:"asc"]

def result = listObjects?.findResult { findEmployeesFor(it, sort) }

...  // then have these methods to actually exercise the type specific findEmployeesFor

def findEmployeesFor(Branch branch, sort) { Employees.findAllByBranch(branch, sort) }
def findEmployeesFor(Department department, sort { Employees.findAllByDepartment(department, sort)}
def findEmployeesFor(Organization organization, sort { Employees.findAllByOrganization(organization, sort)}
def findEmployeesFor(Object obj, sort) { return null } // if listObjects can hold non/branch/department/organization objects
```

I think that this code is actually clearer and it reduces the number of times we iterate over the list and the number of reflection calls we need to make.

Comment: Nice hijack ;--) First you "shorten things up a bit (vs my perfectly valid for in solution)" and then provide one nearly as verbose as the OP's, lol. The question was "Can the code sample below be even smaller?", and clearly it can.  For in with a return on first non-null is exactly that. @tim_yates solution is more in the "spirit" of OP's request; namely, concision.  Apologies for the tone, just annoyed to have my answer copped, ahhh, new & learning the SO ropes ;--)

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it was sort of a hijack.  The original I had was shorter, but didn't actually work if executed for all cases (and neither do the other implementations).  In your edited method, and tim_yate's answer, if `listObjects?.find...` returns null, I believe the findAllBy will return all the Employees with a null Branch/Dept/Org (or it'll blow up, forget which).  That's not what the OP wanted (unless it's true in his system that all employees are required to have a branch and a department and an organization.  Then it'd be fine, but that's hard to know without knowing more.

Comment: Thanks for the honesty ;--) You have heavy rep, particularly in Groovy land, so I defer when applicable. As you say, OP may need to account for listObject null value and affect on given findBy*. Short & sweet is nice, but has to cover all the bases.  Cheers...

Comment: It'd be nice to mark all of these as valid answers - My question was left vague and the three responses have led to some great ways to think about the problem in all respects ("How do I make this shorter" as well as "What is the best way to proceed"). Thanks to everyone for their answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
A for in loop is more efficient, since you want to break processing on first non-null result (i.e. in Groovy we cannot break out of a closure iteration with "return" or "break").

```
def resp   
for(clazz in [Branch,Department,Organization]) {  
    resp = Employees."findAllBy${clazz.name}"(listObjects?.find{it instanceof $clazz})  
    if(resp) return  
}  
if(resp) // do something...
```

**Original**:

```
List results = [Branch,Department,Organization].collect{clazz->  
    Employees."findAllBy${clazz.name}"(listObjects?.find{it instanceof $clazz})  
}
```

Enjoy Groovy ;--)

Comment: I believe I had to make a small change: find{it instanceof $clazz}) was throwing a compilation error so I changed it to find{it.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)} and the compilation went away, I haven't been able to fully test to see if that is the correct approach.

Comment: right, check Old Nabble Grails User forum, there's probably a "grails way" to get return type on dynamic finders: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think [@virtualeyes nearly had it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086039/list-findclosure-and-executing-against-that-value/6086374#6086374), but instead of a collect (which as he says you can't break out of), you want to use a find, as that stops running the first valid result it gets:

```
List results = [Branch,Department,Organization].find { clazz->  
    Employees."findAllBy${clazz.name}"(listObjects?.find{it instanceof clazz})  
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid find{} will only return one of the three classes, not the closure result which we want.

Comment: You're right... Sorry about that... Ted has the answer though :-)